# Copy Lines including carriage return linefeed in notepad++

Tags: copy, notepad++, newline, carriage-return

Using Notepad++ I want to select individual, non-contiguous lines, copy them, and past them and include the CR/LF at the end. Preferrably, I would hold Ctrl, then click the line numbers I want, then press Ctrl+C or right click and select copy; however doing this selects all text (which is frustrating and doesn't make much sense). Furthermore, only selecting the line partially includes the line below it, so that if i press Ctrl+Shift+Up(or down) the line below it also moves up or down.

In summary, I want to copy non-contiguous lines and past them with their respective EOL characters.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to mark desired lines.
2. Menu **Search > Bookmarks > Copy bookmarked lines** will copy these lines into clipboard.

As option for step **1**, you can use **Mark** tab of **Find** dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) with **Mark Line** option checked.

Comment: A blue circle is shown to the left of marked lines. Marks can be set and cleared by clicking where the blue circle is shown. The area showing the blue circles can be hidden, or revealed, via the menu => **Settings** => **Preferences** => **Editing** => **Display bookmark**.